# Как убрать все надписи с яндекс карты и поменять Балун?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Собственно нужно чтобы все элементы навигации и надписи на карте, встроенной на сайт, отсутствовали. А маркер был таким [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что уже пробовали делать?

Comment: Уже сам всё сделал. Добавил карту через API и в коде всё поменял.

Answer (score 1):

Сам пришел к ответу, нужно добавлять карту через API и проводить с ней нужные манипуляции.

```js
 YMaps.jQuery(function() {
   // Создает экземпляр карты и привязывает его к созданному контейнеру
   var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]);

   // Устанавливает начальные параметры отображения карты: центр карты и коэффициент масштабирования
   map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(30.357649, 59.979115), 16);
   // Создание стиля для содержимого балуна
   var baseStyle = new YMaps.Style();
   baseStyle.iconStyle = new YMaps.IconStyle();
   baseStyle.iconStyle.offset = new YMaps.Point(-20, -45);
   baseStyle.iconStyle.size = new YMaps.Point(28, 40);


   var styleFootBall = new YMaps.Style(baseStyle);
   styleFootBall.iconStyle = new YMaps.IconStyle();
   styleFootBall.iconStyle.href = "../img/marker.png";
   var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(new YMaps.GeoPoint(30.357649, 59.979115), {
     style: styleFootBall
   });
   map.addOverlay(placemark);


 })
```